# Post-processing for determining rotor angle of Park transformation

Tags: pmsm, rotor

I have done experiments with a Sinusoidal Axial Flux Permanent Magnet Machine with electrical load, i.e. with the machine as generator. These experiments were done at a constant velocity of the machine, but they differ from each other in the value of velocity. For each experiment, I measured the terminal voltages of the machine, the currents and also the angle of the shaft. This angle measurement was done with the use of an optical encoder. I have all the measurements at each velocity in .csv files and I want to apply to each electrical variable, i.e., voltages and currents, the Park transformation. I know that if I inputted the angle measured in this transformation as the angle between the 'd' and 'A' axes, I would be wrong because there is an offset or bias not considered. Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way to calculate this offset between the angle measured and the angle of Park transformation in my case, which is post-processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to know the offset introduced by the relative positions of encoder and motor.